# How to print math operations vertically?

Tags: python, string

I want to print strings like children in solving math operations, which is like this

```
   32      3801      45      123
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49
-----    ------    ----    -----
```

I have tried it as follows

```
def arithmetic(problems):
# pisahkan setiap value
    atas = [i.split()[0] for i in problems] 
    bawah = [i.split()[2] for i in problems] 
    operator = [i.split()[1] for i in problems] 
    
    output_atas = ""
    output_bawah = ""
 
    for j in range( len(problems) ):
        output_atas += f"{atas[j]:>8}"
        output_bawah += f"{operator[j]}  {bawah[j]:>5}"

 
    print(output_atas)
    print(output_bawah)



arithmetic(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

how to tidy up the string and adjust the line `----` according to the length of the number?

Comment: Find the length of the largest number, add one for the operator, and create that many dashes: `'-'*(max(map(len, numbers))+1)`

Comment: Just a hint: `atas, operator, bawah = zip(*[i.split() for i in problems])`

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line /n in after first value and then operation and next value will be on anew line

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it goes:

1. We iterate through the problems list, and just like you did we split the string to 3 parts: 2 operands and the operator.
2. We use the rjust(width) function which takes the column number to justify the output to the right.
3. The line length variable is just the length of the longest operand + 2 (the operator and the space)
4. After that we print the line.

It can print the result too, the problem is the operations are printed one under the other insted of side by side.

```
def arithmetic(problem_list):
    operand_1 = ''
    operand_2 = ''
    operator = ''

    for problem in problem_list:
        operand_1 = problem.split()[0]
        operator = problem.split()[1]
        operand_2 = problem.split()[2] 

        line_length = max(len(operand_1), len(operand_2)) + 2
        print()
        print(operand_1.rjust(line_length))
        print(operator + " ", operand_2.rjust(line_length - 3))
        print('-' * line_length)
        
        if operator == '+':
            print(str((int(operand_1) + int(operand_2))).rjust(line_length))
        if operator == '-':
            print(str((int(operand_1) - int(operand_2))).rjust(line_length))

        print('__' * 16)
```